# How do I execute each command in a list?

Tags: makefile

If I have a list of *n* commands, *c* = *c1* ... *cn*, how can I execute them in order for a given target? I tried the *foreach* construct

```
$(foreach x,$(c),./$(x))
```

but that puts all the commands on one line. Any clues?

Comment: Sounds like you want bash for that more than Make.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You identified the problem (“but that puts all the commands on one line”). You just need to append a newline whenever you expand `$x` in your loop.

```
define \n


endef
```

Now simply use `$(foreach x,$c,./$(x)${\n})` in your recipe.

Answer (score 14):

If there is no need to check for success, then adding semicolon should work:

```
$(foreach x,$c,./$(x);)
```

If you need to fail if one of the command in the list returns failure, you need to break it in steps. Instead of directly executing the commands, we wrap the execution in a make function:

```
define execute-command
$(1)

endef

execute-list:
        $(foreach x,$(c),$(call execute-command,./$(x)))
```

Comment: You don't need to prefix the expansion of each line with a tab. _Make_ realises each line represents a new command in the recipe due to the tab already.

Comment: @bobbogo - nice, thanks. Simplified the answer per your suggestion.